# Sprite only moves in one direction when two buttons are held

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I am trying to make my sprite move a unit every so often. It works up until multiple keys are held down at the same time. If this is the case it moves in one direction, depending on which direction is programmed first in the code. To me, it seems my sprite should move in both directions as the if statements are not if else statements. If I go up and to the left it SHOULD move 1 unit up and 1 unit to the left. How can I get it to do this?

```
public Transform timmyTransform;
private float timer= 0;
public float movementDelay;


void Update()
{

    timer += Time.deltaTime;
    if (Input.GetAxis("Vertical") < 0 && timer > movementDelay)
    {
        timer = 0;
        timmyTransform.transform.position += new Vector3(0, -1, 0);
    }
    if (Input.GetAxis("Vertical") > 0 && timer > movementDelay)
    {
        timer = 0;
        timmyTransform.transform.position += new Vector3(0, 1, 0);
    }
    if (Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") < 0 && timer>movementDelay)
    {
        timer = 0;
        timmyTransform.transform.position += new Vector3(-1, 0, 0);
    }
    if(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") > 0 && timer > movementDelay)
    {
        timer = 0;
        timmyTransform.transform.position += new Vector3(1, 0, 0);
    }
```

}

Comment: Umm you seems to set the ```timer = 0```, so the succeeding check for ```timer > movementDelay``` will return false and skip the rest of the directions. (I think ```movementDelay``` will never be negative...)

Comment: Adding to @Alphaharrius comment, you probably want a `bool moved`, set that to true if you hit one of those blocks, then at the end zero out the timer.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is the `timer`.

You always set it to `0` so after the first button press is handled the other conditions are never met.

I would rather do something like e.g.

```
timer += Time.deltaTime;
// Get and store the Input ONCE
var vertical = Mathf.Sign(Input.GetAxis("Vertical"));
var horizontal = Mathf.Sign(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"));
// directly get the movement as a vector so you can use vector maths
var movement = new Vector2(horizontal, vertical);

// Check whether there currently is any input and timer is due
if (movement.sqrMagnitude > 0 && timer > movementDelay)
{
    timer = 0;

    // directly use the movement as it is already the vector based on the input
    timmyTransform.transform.position += movement;
}
```